# How to convert cURL cookies to a Firefox sqlite cookies?

Tags: php, sqlite, firefox, curl, cookies

I need to convert the cookies text file geenrated by `cURL` into a firefox sqlite cookies database, to replace the `cookies.sqlite` file in my firefox profile folder, so that I can open firefox with the new cookies.

I wrote the following code which seems to be working, but, when I open firefox the new `cookies.sqlite` file gets deleted and replaced by a backup one:

```
<?php

class CookiesDatabase extends SQLite3
{
    const DROP_TABLE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moz_cookies";
    const CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'moz_cookies'
    (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        baseDomain TEXT,
        originAttributes TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        name TEXT,
        value TEXT,
        host TEXT,
        path TEXT,
        expiry INTEGER,
        lastAccessed INTEGER,
        creationTime INTEGER,
        isSecure INTEGER,
        isHttpOnly INTEGER,
        inBrowserElement INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        CONSTRAINT moz_uniqueid UNIQUE
        (
            name,
            host,
            path,
            originAttributes
        )
    );";

    const CREATE_INDEXES_QUERY = "
    CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS moz_basedomain
    ON
    moz_cookies
    (
        baseDomain,
        originAttributes
    );";

    const INSERT_QUERY = "
    INSERT INTO moz_cookies
    (
        baseDomain,
        name,
        value,
        host,
        path,
        expiry,
        lastAccessed,
        creationTime,
        isSecure,
        isHttpOnly
    ) 
    VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d, %d, %d, %d, %d)";

    function __construct ($output)
    {
        $this->open ($output);
        $this->createTable();
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

    public function createTable()
    {
        if ($this->exec (self::DROP_TABLE_QUERY))
        {
            if ($this->exec (self::CREATE_TABLE_QUERY))
            {
                if ($this->exec (self::CREATE_INDEXES_QUERY))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        echo $this->lastErrorMsg() . "\n";
        return false;
    }

    public function insert ($data)
    {
        $query = sprintf
        (
            self::INSERT_QUERY,
            $data->baseDomain,
            $data->name,
            $data->value,
            $data->host,
            $data->path,
            $data->expiry,
            time(),
            time(),
            $data->isSecure,
            $data->isHttpOnly
        );

        if (!$this->exec ($query))
        {
            echo $this->lastErrorMsg() . "\n";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function convert ($input)
    {
        if (!file_exists ($input))
        {
            echo "Error: $input does not exist!\n";
            return false;
        }
        $lines = file ($input);
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            if (substr ($line, 0, 2) == '# ') continue;
            if (substr_count ($line, "\t") != 6) continue;

            $tokens = explode ("\t", $line);
            $tokens = array_map ('trim', $tokens);
            $domain = $tokens[0];
            $isHttpOnly = false;
            if (substr ($domain, 0, 10) == '#HttpOnly_')
            {
                $isHttpOnly = true;
                $domain = substr ($domain, 10);
            }
            if ($domain[0] == '.')
            {
                $domain = substr ($domain, 1);
            }
            $isSecure = ($tokens[3] == 'TRUE') ? 1 : 0;

            $data = (object) array
            (
                'host' => 'host.com',
                'baseDomain' => $domain,
                'isDomainShared' => $tokens[1],
                'path' => $tokens[2],
                'isSecure' => $isSecure,
                'expiry' => $tokens[4],
                'name' => $tokens[5],
                'value' => $tokens[6],
                'isHttpOnly' => $isHttpOnly
            );

            if (!$this->insert ($data))
            {
                echo "Error: Failed to insert row to database\n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // End of class CookiesDatabase
}


?>
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
<?php

    require_once ('CookiesDatabase.class.php');

    $db = new CookiesDatabase ('cookies.sqlite');
    if ($db)
    {
        if ($db->convert ('cookie.txt'))
        {
            echo "Conversion successful.\n";
        }
        else echo "Conversion Failed!\n";
    }
    else echo "Failed to open database!\n";

?>
```

Why is firefox deleting it?

**Edit:**

I'm using Firefox 57.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: This is not a php question.

Comment: You really shouldn't open the original file yourself (since Firefox probably has a soft flock on it). Make a copy and open that instead.